# How to reference a variable outside of function in python

Tags: python

I am trying to reference variables root1 and root 2 in the function `Print(numA, numB, numC, root1, root2, EquationKind)`, however, I do not want to use global variables.

I get the error message:

> Line 54: NameError: name 'root1' is not defined

Here is my code:

```
import math

def main():
    while True:
        def GetInputs():
            numA = int(input("What is coefficient A?"))
            numB = int(input("What is coefficient B?"))
            numC = int(input("What is coefficient C?"))
            return numA, numB, numC

        def QuadRoots(numA, numB, numC):
            if numA == 0:
                return -1
        
            else:
                discriminant = numB ** 2 - (4 * (numA * numC))
        
                if discriminant < 0:
                    return -2
            
                elif discriminant > 0:
                    numnegB = numB * -1
                    plussolution = numnegB + math.sqrt(numB ** 2 - (4 * (numA * numC))) 
                    minussolution =  numnegB - math.sqrt(numB ** 2 - (4 * (numA * numC)))
                    root1 = plussolution / (2 * numA)  
                    root2 = minussolution / (2 * numA)  
                    return 0, root1, root2
                
                elif discriminant == 0:
                    numnegB = numB * -1
                    root1 = numnegB / (2 * numA)
                    return 1, root1
                
        numA, numB, numC = GetInputs()
        EquationKind = QuadRoots(numA, numB, numC)
    
        def Print(numA, numB, numC, root1, root2, EquationKind):
            if EquationKind == -1:
                print("This is a line; not a Quadratic Equation.")
                
            elif EquationKind == -2:
                print(str(numB) + "x^2" + " + " + str(numA) + "x" + " + " + str(numC) + " has no  solution.") 
            
            elif EquationKind == 0:
                print(str(numB) + "x^2" + " + " + str(numA) + "x" + " + " + str(numC) + " has solutions " + str(root1) + " and " + str(root2) + ".")
            
            elif EquationKind == 1:
                print(str(numB) + "x^2" + " + " + str(numA) + "x" + " + " + str(numC) + " has unique solution " + str(root1) + ".")
                                        
         
        Print(numA, numB, numC, root1, root2, EquationKind)

        askuser = input("Do you want to solve another equation? Type Y for yes and N for no:")
        
        if askuser == "N" or askuser == "n":
            print("Goodbye!")
            break
            
        elif askuser == "Y" or askuser == "y":
            continue
        
        else:
            print("Please type Y or N")
            break
            
main()
```

The goal of the program is to solve quadratic equations, it should test to see if the equation has a solution or not.

For example, if the user entered numbers **1, 3, and 2**, the output should be **3x^2 + 1x + 2 has solutions -1.0 and -2.0.**

Comment: You have two options: make them global, or return them from `QuadRoots()` and capture the values when you call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `QuadRoot` function is problematic. If there are 2 roots, it returns `EquationKind, root1, root2`, one root it returns `EquationKind, root1` and leaves `root2` undefined, else, it returns just `EquationKind` and leaves `root1, root2` undefined.

This makes it very hard to deal with and very error-prone. I suggest rewriting the function so that it always has the same return type.

```
def QuadRoots(numA, numB, numC):
    if numA == 0:
        # EquationKind = -1
        # root1 = root2 = None
        return -1, None, None

    else:
        discriminant = numB ** 2 - (4 * (numA * numC))

        if discriminant < 0:
            # EquationKind = -2
            # root1 = root2 = None
            return -2, None, None
    
        elif discriminant > 0:
            numnegB = numB * -1
            plussolution = numnegB + math.sqrt(numB ** 2 - (4 * (numA * numC))) 
            minussolution =  numnegB - math.sqrt(numB ** 2 - (4 * (numA * numC)))
            root1 = plussolution / (2 * numA)  
            root2 = minussolution / (2 * numA)

            # EquationKind = 0
            # root1 != root2
            return 0, root1, root2
        
        else:
            numnegB = numB * -1
            root1 = numnegB / (2 * numA)

            # EquationKind = 1
            # root1 = root2
            return 1, root1, root1
```

Then, you call it like this:

```
EquationKind, root1, root2 = QuadRoots(numA, numB, numC)
```

Now `root1, root2` are always defined. They are equal if the function only has one root, and are `None` if there are no roots.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response and the function fix. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in line 38 you are assigning the value to the variable EquationKind regardless of whether you return 1, 2 or 3 values. So variables root1, root2 only exist during the execution of the QuadRoots method.

If you look at the variables numA, numB, numC you have declared them out of the method.

One option you can use (although I think not the most optimal) is to add:
EquationKind, root1, root2 = QuadRoots(numA, numB, numC) and in the Quadroots method always return 3 values.

I hope I have helped you